# adding multiple rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big problem that somebody is attacking me by adding multiple rows into my db. Hes using the form I have on my website. I got about 2500 rows in my db and all rows were different. Its been generating by any script. Do you have any suggestions how I can fix it? this is my form I have on my website

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['type'])) {$type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);}
if(isset($_POST['ip'])) {$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ip']);}
if(isset($_POST['port'])) {$port = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['port']);}
$add_date = time();
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);}
if(isset($_POST['web'])) {$web = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['web']);}
if(isset($_POST['mod'])) {$mod = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mod']);}


echo "
<form action='#' method='post'>

<legend>Formulár pre pridanie serveru</legend>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
Hra:
</td>
<td>
<select name='type'>
<option value='cs16'>Counter Strike 1.6</option>
<option value='source'>Counter Strike Source</option>
<option value='csgo'>Counter Strike Global Offensive</option>
</select>
(vyberte hru)
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>              
Typ:
</td>
<td>
<select name='mod'>";

$modes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `lgsl_modes`") or die(mysql_error());
while($modes_names = mysql_fetch_array($modes))
{
echo '<option value="'.$modes_names['mod'].'">'.$modes_names['name'].'</option>';
}

echo "</select>
(vyberte herný mód)
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>              
IP serveru:
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='ip' value='' required>
(iba číslice a bodky)
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>              
Port serveru:
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='port' value='' required>
(iba číslice)
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>               
Web serveru:
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='web' value='' required>
(uvádzajte bez začiatočného http://)
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>              
Váš email:
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='email' value='' required>
(kontaktný email)
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type='submit' name='odoslat' value='Odoslať'>
</td>
</tr>
</table>            
</form>
";


if($ip) if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}$/",$ip)) $usermsgip="Ip adresa bola uvedená v zlom tvare.";
if($port) if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{5}$/",$port)) $usermsgport="Port bol uvedený v zlom tvare.";
if($email) if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/",$email)) $usermsgemail="Email bol uvedený v zlom tvare.";    
if($web) if(!preg_match("%^((https?://)|(www\.))([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i" ,$web)) $usermsgweb="Web bol uvedený v zlom tvare.";

if(isset($_POST['odoslat']) && $usermsgip || $usermsgport || $usermsgemail || $usermsgweb) {
if($usermsgip) echo $usermsgip."<br>";
if($usermsgport) echo $usermsgport."<br>";
if($usermsgemail) echo $usermsgemail."<br>";
if($usermsgweb) echo $usermsgweb."<br>";
}


if(isset($_POST['odoslat']) && !$usermsgip && !$usermsgport && !$usermsgemail && !$usermsgweb) {
$kontrola = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `lgsl` WHERE `ip`='".$ip."' AND `c_port`=".$port);                                                                                  
if(mysql_num_rows($kontrola)) {echo "Server už bol pridaný do banlistu.";}
else { 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `lgsl` (`type`, `ip`, `c_port`, `q_port`, `disabled`, `add_date`, `email`, `web`, `mod`) 
VALUES ('$type', '$ip', '$port', '$port', '1', '$add_date', '$email', '$web', '$mod')");
echo 'Server bol úspešne odoslaný na schválenie.';
} 
} 
?>
```

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You need to do some sort of form validation and perhaps a captcha to prevent someone from automatically filling out the form and therefore adding data.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rewrite the whole script using PDO. With Pdo you can avoid SQL-Injection in easy way. Here's a [link](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) where you can find that and all the web is full of guide and examples.

Anyway if you want to fix your script you can use Captcha to avoid automatic form submit and a library to sanitize input.

Here you find a simple [captcha example](https://www.phpcaptcha.org/) and a [good sanitize library](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

You can whatch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) some good tips to solve problems.

Hope this helps.